# How do I assign byte in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, byte, assign

I am trying to assign byes in a ByteArray in Kotlin, I just don't know the syntax of assigning a byte.

for example in c if I want to assign a char I would do:
`char c = 'a';`

But what is the syntax for assigning a byte in a byte type variable in Kotlin language ? I just can't find an example, let's say I want to assign the byte E0 in array[i], how do I do it?

Comment: `array[i] = 0xE0.toByte()`?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Answer (score 11):

It's a simple assignment. You just need to be sure the value you want to assign is in the byte range:

```
array[i] = -32
```

or

```
array[i] = 0xE0.toByte()
```

or even

```
array[i] = 224.toByte()
```

Comment: (0xA1).toByte()